# KeyAbsent when using Association in a replacement

Tags: replacement, rule

I am trying to replace derivatives with other functions. I expected

```
as = Association[fx -> dfx]
Derivative[1][fx][x] /. Derivative[1][y_][_] -> as[y]
```

to replace my derivative fx'(x) with a call to dfx. Instead, I am getting

```
Missing["KeyAbsent", fx]
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Use `:> as[y]` not `->`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.